# Spring Boot how to use jdbcTemplate to convert into custom JSON/OBJECT

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, resultset, jdbctemplate

I've been programming with java for years. So far I have not used any frameworks in the backend or in the frontend area. I want to change this in the future because I think a lot of the security features of Spring Boot.

Now I've encountered a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I have a table in the database that contains customer and item data.

Table in Database:

| Customer | Customer Descipt | Article | ArticleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | Customer1Des | Article1 | Phone |
| Customer1 | Customer1Des | Article2 | Notebook |
| Customer2 | Customer2Des | Article1 | Phone |
| Customer3 | Customer2Des | Article1 | Phone |

My Query for Example:

`SELECT * FROM ORDER BY CUSTOMER!`

JSON I NEED:

```
{
  Customer: "Customer1",
  CustomerDescription: "Customer1Des"
  ArticlesLIST: [
    {
       Articlenumber: "Article1",
       ArticleName: "Phone"
    },
    {...}
  ]
},
{
  Customer: "Customer2",
  CustomerDescription: "Customer2Des"
  Articles: [
    {
       Articlenumber: "Article2",
       ArticleName: "Notebook"
    },
    {...}
  ]
},
```

In my old Structure wihout Framework it was easy to do it. I take the Resultset -> take it in a WHILE and do my Logic to generate this JSON.

```
String lastcustomer="";
while(rs.nex()){
  //My Logic to build JSONObjects and JSONArrays ...

  if(!lastcustomer.equals(rs.getString("Customer"){
    //Look if next Customer Name is not same as before so generate a new JSONObject and JSONArray 
  }

  ... //JSON Generate
  lastcustomer = rs.getString("Customer");
}
```

BUT IN SPRING BOOT how can I do it? I use jdbcTemplate for SQL statements... The problem is: it is not possible to split the database structure. In jdbcTemplate I don't get the whole result set I can only catch the next() Element.

Unfortunately I can't find the clue...

Answer (score 0):

`jdbcTemplate` does not translate between formats,
it is strictly for executing queries.
Use a tool to convert between an object (or a list of objects) and JSON.
I like `Jackson` (here is a [Baeldung Jackson Tutorial link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson).
There are other,
popular tools including,
but not limited to,
Gson and SimpleJson.

Take the output of your successful query and run it through
`ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString` to convert it to JSON.

An alternative is to have Spring Boot perform the translation for you.
A way to achieve this is to have your RestController handler method return
`ResponseEntity<List<TypeOutputByYourQuery>>` and Spring Boot will perform the conversion for you.